# Unity standalone build not running

Tags: windows, windows-7, unity-game-engine, windows-8.1

I am making a Unity3D game. I have built that game as Windows standalone build x86_x64. I have uploaded it on Google drive after making a rar file. Then shared the link to my client.

When he downloaded it was not opened. Windows 7 Ultimate 32 bit on his computer showed this message **the version of this file is not compatible**.

What is the problem? It is working n my PC perfectly for x86 build , x86_64 builds. My PC has Windows 8.1 Pro.

Please let me know about the actual problem.

Answer (score 5):

If you select to build your game as **Windows x86_x64**, this means you're building the 64-bit version of your game.

Because your client's computer is running a 32-bit version of Windows, your 64-bit game build will not run.

To resolve, build your game using just **Windows x86** and it should work on your client's 32-bit Windows system.